# Python can't find existing file in same folder

Tags: python, path, openai-whisper

.py and .mp3 file are in the same folder

Full code:

```
import whisper

file_path = r"E:\test\oid.mp3"
print(file_path)


model = whisper.load_model("base")
result = model.transcribe(file_path)
print(result["text"])
```

I got the file directory as output. but the code does not see it

I wrote only the name of the file, I wrote the full file extension, I wrote it as raw.

Also updated file permissions:

```
C:\Users\erina>icacls E:\test\oid.mp3
E:\test\oid.mp3 DESKTOP-PK8T69J\erina:(F)
                BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(M)
                BUILTIN\Users:(RX)
                BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
                BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Python version 3.10

Comment: You probably want to change your variable name `str` - str is also the built in string type name.

Comment: Same problem even with different variable name

Comment: I don't understand your problem, perhaps because I don't understand what `whisper.load_model` is supposed to do. If this error is specific to `whisper`, you should say so in the title and tags.

Comment: It would help if you included the actual output (not a description like "I got the file directory") and the intended output. Also, a directory listing (using `os.listdir`, for example) would help.

Comment: Please print the value of `model` so that we know it's loading the model correctly. It would also help to know what virtual environment setup you're using.